# Reading mediumblob in C# mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, blob

I'm looking to read a blob file from the mysql database and display the "hash" segment of the blob.

Here's what I have tried.

```
MySqlConnection _connection = new MySqlConnection("Database=forum;Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;Password=");
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT data FROM xf_user_authenticate WHERE user_id=1", _connection);

        _connection.Open();

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        FileStream fs;
        Byte[] bindata;

        bindata = (byte[])(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

        ms.Write(bindata, 0, bindata.Length);

        API.consoleOutput($"{bindata.Length} - {bindata.ToString()}");
```

This outputs to a console with the result being

```
97 - 58
```

But this is the contents of my blob

```
a:1:{s:4:"hash";s:60:"$2y$10$myhashishere";}
```

Comment: MySQL's example uses a reader and GetBytes(); are you sure ExecuteScalar returns a byte[]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is ascii encoded byte array, you can get the string back using

```
ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetChars(bindata)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. This seems to output nothing? Just  a blank space

Comment: @Moretti what is API.consoleOutput?

Comment: @Uueerdo it's basically Console.WriteLine. I'm writing this inside some API handlers for a game server.

Comment: And if you use Console.WriteLine?

Comment: @Uueerdo It's still blank

Comment: @Moretti attach a debugger and see whats the content of bindata. (based on your length output it should be 97 ints)

Comment: @Steve Would you be able to give an example on how to read the contents?

Comment: @Moretti well its a byte array. you can just do string.Join(",", bindata);

Comment: Sorry for the lengthy reply. This is the output

`97,58,49,58,123,115,58,52,58,34,104,97,115,104,34,59,115,58,54,48,58,34,36,50,121,36,49,48,36,50,117,89,73,54,53,89,47,73,47,77,122,50,102,105,118,106,118,73,50,88,46,86,88,72,87,89,81,111,72,49,70,102,78,73,53,104,49,119,56,46,87,112,121,49,107,80,116,86,76,81,75,67,34,59,125 `

Comment: Thanks for that @Steve I seem to be getting each letter instead of objects. `2018-05-07 21:46:38.2863 |  Info | DesearlizeTest | a 
2018-05-07 21:46:38.3118 |  Info | DesearlizeTest | : 
2018-05-07 21:46:38.3908 |  Info | DesearlizeTest | 1 
2018-05-07 21:46:38.4113 |  Info | DesearlizeTest | : 
2018-05-07 21:46:38.4488 |  Info | DesearlizeTest | { 
2018-05-07 21:46:38.4913 |  Info | DesearlizeTest | s `

Comment: `_connection.Open();

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            byte[] bindata;
            
            bindata = (byte[])(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

            //ms.Write(bindata, 0, bindata.Length);

           Char[] coded = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetChars(bindata);`

Comment: @Moretti which is correct. You are getting back a char array which you can then use something like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx to deserialize it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Steve got it working! Had to make it a string instead of Char and got it to separate it up.